# No puedo insertar miles de registros en mysql con C#

Tags: mysql, c#

Estoy empezando a utilizar MySql y al insertar miles de registros me dice que los campos de mi DATABLE no son iguales a los de mi TABLA

Ya que en el DATATABLE vienen en mayúsculas y en la TABLA estan en minúsculas, ya cambie los nombres a mayúsculas en la TABLA pero tampoco funciono, cual sería la solución?

Este es mi código:

```
public static Boolean InsertaCapaCero(DataTable dtCapaCero)
{
ConexionSQL conexionSql = new ConexionSQL();
MySqlTransaction sqltran;
using (conexionSql.conectardb)
{
conexionSql.conectardb.Open();
sqltran = conexionSql.conectardb.BeginTransaction();

try
{
var bulk = new BulkOperation(conexionSql.conectardb);
bulk.DestinationTableName = "capacero";
bulk.BulkInsert(dtCapaCero);
sqltran.Commit();

return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
sqltran.Rollback();
conexionSql.conectardb.Close();
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR InsertaCapaCero", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
throw;
}
}
}
```

Estos son los mensajes de error:

-- An error occured while resolving AutoMap.ByName. See the inner exception for details.

-- Missing Column : ALMACEN_ID
On Table : `capacero`

Gracias por su ayuda!!!

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu tabla y tu dataTable

Comment: Dice que te falta la columna ALMACEN_ID en tu tabla capacero. Asegurate que dicha columna este en tu tabla con ese nombre.